# How to specify connection string/impersonation user/password in SSAS CD deploy?

Tags: jenkins, deployment, ssas

I've seen discussions that hover around this in the past but never a direct solution (or "you can't do that"). I manage a Jenkins CI/CD system. We build and deploy SSAS Tabular and Dimensional models. We run DevEnv to build it, Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe /s to create a deployment script and then run the script.

The BI group has requested the ability to specify in the deploy configuration the credentials for the connection string and the impersonation user. Deployment.exe creates files that it appears could be modified to include the credentials but the MS docs don't give the actual schema/properties/values to use.

Anyone have any success doing this?

Comment: Wow. Nothing? Nobody?

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/deployment-script-files-solution-deployment-config-settings) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/running-the-analysis-services-deployment-wizard), perhaps you could solve this by running the deployment wizard in answer file mode (/a switch) and tell the development team that they can provide their required settings by committing an answer file to source control and then your team could integrate this answer file into a pipeline with batch or powershell scripts.

Comment: I've seen those but the description of the information in the answer file is generic. What is the schema of the answer file? Sections? Key names? Do you have any links to the actual format for an answer file for SSAS?     I did some more poking around looking for answers on answer files and found [this](http://blog.boxedbits.com/archives/50) and [this](http://msftasprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2005!Readme%20For%20Command-line%20Utility%20Sample&referringTitle=Home). It's not the answer to answer files, but it may be another approach.

Comment: I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/deployment-script-files-input-used-to-create-deployment-script

Comment: See https://azurebi.jppp.org/2015/05/18/unraveling-the-microsoft-analysis-services-deployment-wizard/ and also  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b5da324b-4b3e-43cd-86ec-a7b24cb22804/ssas-deployment-wizard-data-source-connection-string-userid-and-password-getting-removed?forum=sqlanalysisservices

Comment: @AndrewGray this is the same doc I've been reading and frustrated with. I don't get a configsettings file out of deployment.exe so I can't change it. There doesn't appear to be any doc as to what the schema of the file is so I can't manufacture one.